# Given the mounted volume's URL, retrieve the DMG file's URL using Swift

Tags: swift, metadata, dmg, mounted-volumes, diskarbitration

[image]

I have the URL of the mounted volume which is, `/Volumes/Brave Browser`. How can I retrieve the URL of the disk image file using Swift? As you can see from the screenshot, it's filepath is `/Users/saisudheep_n/Downloads/Brave-Browser.dmg`. I have tried using Disk Arbitration to retrieve disk description using `DADiskCopyDescription(DADisk_Object)` but it doesn't contain the dmg filepath. Is there any way to achieve this using Swift?

Comment: Use `FileManager`'s `mountedVolumeURLs` to list all the URLs of the removable and find the path that starts with 'Volumes.'

Comment: There's this [answer using the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/335223/122145) and also an [Objective-C example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1785524/2227743).